Multithreading in Azure Api
I need to write almost 300 different wiki page all separated by type : [Epic, Features, ....] using Azure devops python Api
And this take me many minutes when i write them one by one
So i tried to do a basic multithreading
if (multithreading):
        threads = []
        for task in task_list:
            thread = threading.Thread(target=write_one_epic, args=(task, requests_session)
            thread.start()
            threads.append(thread)
        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()

This result me in this error
The wiki page operation failed with message : TF401028: The reference 'refs/heads/wikiMaster' has already been updated by another client, so you cannot update it. Please try again.
Update, i tried with a ThreadPoolExecutor and it result me as the same error
The error is raised when i try to create a new page
wiki.create_or_update_page(content, Constant.project, Constant.wikiIdentifier, self.actual_path, None)


That sounds like it's backed by a Git repository, and concurrent operations that would write to the master ref fail. The easiest fix of course is to just add retry logic...


The wiki page operation failed with message : TF401028: The reference 'refs/heads/wikiMaster' has already been updated by another client, so you cannot update it. Please try again.

It could happen when running parallel updates to the same wiki.
You can only push to the remote if you are up to date, try to pull the data before update, and put in a retry loop and small interval between each try. please check the similar link here for the details.
In addition, the Azure DevOps python api is a thin wrapper around the Azure DevOps REST APIs. You can try to use the REST API directly for this operation. You can find the sample script in link here.

Thanks, but is the multithread still worth in term of time when we add all those computation and delay or optimizing the classic way is a better idea.
Because for me the goal of the multithreading was to create the pages faster

multithread is a good idea, but the project wiki stores in git repo actually, the problem is caused by how Git works, i'm afraid you could need to change the way to create the wiki.
